# How do i load a file with strings with D3 (like in processing)

Tags: javascript, json, file, d3.js, readfile

I'm currently working on making a website with d3. The website with include a scatterplot, where I have the need to load some txt files with data and some php files that can call a MySQL database for data as well.

In processing I used loadStrings() to get my data and to run the php file with specific arguments, but I have only been able to find ways to load JSON format files through D3. Is it possible to load a file of strings seperated with a tab or something of the sort, for instance:

```
t(15;17)    inv(16)/t(16;16)    t(8;21) t(15;17)    t(8;21) t(11q23)/MLL
```

I don't have my data in a JSON format. I either have them seperated with a newline, tabs or comma. Some help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: Yes, e.g. [`d3.tsv()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/CSV#tsv).

Comment: Refer this link [d3 data parsing](http://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/CSV)